# Codeigniter get specific record in table

Tags: codeigniter

I practicing CI and loop through all records in a view and produces each link as below:

```
sitename.com/products/2
```

where `2` is id of certain product, I want to click on the link and get this product information in product page, how can I create a model to retrieve specific record?

**Model:**

```
class Db_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}


public function getProduct($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_product', array('id' => $id));
    return $query->result();
}

}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Products extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('db_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['rows'] = $this->db_model->getProduct($id);

    $this->load->view('product', $data);
}


}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You already have a function in model which retrieves specific record...You need to have a controller

Comment: what's the problem you are facing. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Venkat, I get message `404 Page Not Found` when access `sitename.com/products/2` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index function doesn't take $id as a parameter, So you need to modify your index function, Use the following index function, which I've edited.

```
public function index($id)
{
    $data['rows'] = $this->db_model->getProduct($id);

    $this->load->view('product', $data);
}
```

Comment: I added $id as parameter, when I go to url `sitename.com/products/2`, it show `404 Page Not Found`.

Comment: try using this url : sitename.com/index.php/products/2

Comment: I had edited routing to avoid index.php show on url, how ever I try `index.php/products/2` still not success.

Comment: You've to use sitename.com/listing/2.... because u're calling from Listing Controller.... And also the name of ur controller is Listing

Comment: I have changed filename and controller to 'Products'. may be is a routing rules issue? what do ya think?

Comment: I try `sitename.com/products/` without id value, message show `Message: Missing argument 1 for Products::index()`, header content can display properly.

Comment: buddy... u might have changed filename.. but i think ur controller name is still Listing.... As you re getting     Message: Missing argument 1 for Listing::index() This error

Comment: No luck, I confirmed filename is products.php and controller is `class Products extends CI_Controller`.

Comment: I tried so many attempts now its works when I have url like `sitename.com/products/index/2`. Now is how to strip away `index` to make url clean.